# Syntax of a pointer for array of objects as member of another class

Tags: c++

Hello I have two files that define classes.
In one of them I am trying declare an array of classes of another class using a pointer, I have some troubles with syntax, how I declare this in the first file? thank you in advance

the first file :

```
 #ifndef YARD_H_INCLUDED
 #define YARD_H_INCLUDED
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 class yard
 {
 public:
     int yard_size;
     car *car_array[];
     int cars_in_yard;

     yard();

     void show() const
     {
       for (int i=0; i<=cars_in_yard;i++)
       {
        car_array[i]->show();
       }
     }

     ~yard()
     {
       yard_size=0;
       delete car_array[cars_in_yard];
       cars_in_yard= 0;
     }
 };
 #endif // YARD_H_INCLUDED'
```

the second one is:

```
 #ifndef CAR_H_INCLUDED
 #define CAR_H_INCLUDED
 #include <iostream>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string>

 using namespace std;

 class car
 {
 public:
     char car_name[80];
     double price;
     int eng;

     car();

     void show() const
     {
          cout<<"Car Make : "<< *car_name <<" , Price: "<< price<<" , Engine : "<< eng <<"     , cc";
     }
 };

 car::car() 
 {
    car_name[0]=0;
    price=0.0;
    eng=0;
 }
 #endif // CAR_H_INCLUDED'
```

Comment: Like this: `std::vector<car> car_array`

Comment: Unfortunately vectors not allowed.... :/

Comment: it seems that `#include "car.h"` is missing in the first file.

Comment: All this "no standard library features allowed" makes me wonder why people aren't being taught good honest C instead of crippled C++ with associated bad habits.

Comment: where is `yard::yard()` defined?

Comment: By the way, your `delete car_array[]` statement deletes memory for a single slot.  The correct syntax for deleting the entire array is `delete [] car_array;`.  Note the position of the square brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well thanks for everybody who answered.. had no time to reply
The problem is solved :)
after some modifications and pain:
code:
first file

```
#ifndef YARD_H_INCLUDED
#define YARD_H_INCLUDED
#include "car.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class yard
{
private:
int yard_size;
car **car_array;
int cars_in_yard;
public:
yard(int t_yard_size)
{
    yard_size=t_yard_size;
    car_array= new car *[yard_size];
    cars_in_yard=0;
}
~yard()
{
    for(int i=0; i<cars_in_yard; i++)
    {
        delete car_array[i];
    }
}
void show() const
{
  for (int i=0; i<cars_in_yard; i++)
  {
    car_array[i]->show();
  }
}
int num_Of_cars()
{
    return cars_in_yard;
}
void add_car(car *);
void show_last();
bool place();
};


#endif // YARD_H_INCLUDED
```

The Cpp of yard.h

```
#include "yard.h"
#include "car.h"

void yard::add_car(car *t_car)
{
if (yard_size == cars_in_yard)
{
    cout<< "There is no place in a Yard"<<endl;
}
else
{
    car_array[cars_in_yard++] = t_car;
    cout<<"New car added successfully"<<endl;
}
}
void yard::show_last()
{
car_array[cars_in_yard-1]->show();
}
bool yard::place()
{
if (yard_size==cars_in_yard)
{
    cout<<"There is no place in a Yard"<<endl;
    return false;
}
else
{
    return true;
}
}
```

and finally the car.h

```
#ifndef CAR_H_INCLUDED
#define CAR_H_INCLUDED
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class car
{   private:
char car_name[80];
double price;
int eng;
public:
car()
{
    price=0.0;
    eng=0;
}
car(char t_car_name[],int t_price, int t_eng)
{
    strcat(car_name, t_car_name);
    price = t_price;
    eng = t_eng;
}
void show()
{
  std::cout<<"Car Make : "<< car_name <<" , Price: "<< price<<" $ , Engine : "<< eng <<" cc ."<<std::endl;
}
};


#endif // CAR_H_INCLUDED
```

Answer (score 1):

`car *car_array[];` is a syntax error. Array sizes must be known at compile time.  To use runtime sizing, you need to use dynamic memory allocation.

Based on `Yard`'s destructor; it seems like the cars in this array are supposed to "belong" to the Yard - i.e. the Yard is responsible for clearing them.

It would be simpler to have the Yard store an array of `car`, instead of storing an array of `car *`. But I'm assuming you've decided to store an array of `car *` instead.

Of course the simplest way to do that is `std::vector<car*> car_array;` (or arguably, a vector of `unique_ptr`).  However, since you're supposed to reinvent the wheel, you need to do the following things:

- `car **car_array;`
- In the constructors, initialize this (perhaps to `nullptr`)
- make `yard_size` and `cars_in_yard` private - your Yard needs to accurately be able to keep track of how much memory is in use
- Whenever `yard_size` is updated, if it got bigger you need to `new[]` some new space for `car *`'sand copy over values from the old space, and `delete[]` the old space
- Whenever `cars_in_yard` is increased you need to check if you need to increase `yard_size`
- Whenever `cars_in_yard` is decreased you need to delete the cars that are no longer in the yard, and shuffle everything down so there are no gaps (unless of course you want to allow gaps, but then your insertion logic is more complicated)
- Have a copy-constructor, a copy-assignment operator that either do the right thing or are disabled
- Have a destructor that deletes the cars in the yard and also `car_array`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this evil technique:

```
#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 64
struct car
{
  char * p_name;
  car() : p_name(NULL)
  { }

  car(char const * const p_new_name)
  {
    if (p_name)
    {
        delete [] p_name;
    }
    const unsigned int size = strlen(p_new_name) + 1; // Remember that terminating nul char
    p_name = new char(size);
    strcpy(p_name, p_new_name);  // Make a copy of the parameter string
  }
};
```

If you really wanted to use dynamic memory correctly, your class would teach you to use smart or unique pointers.

The technique is evil since it is not using a tested data structure that uses dynamic memory, such as `std::string` or `std::vector`.

**Edit 1:**
Yes, evil, because the destructor doesn't exist and the compiler generated destructor would not free up the dynamic memory.  Evil because it could lead to mistakes in the code above.

Adding the constructor:

```
  ~car()
  {
    delete [] p_name; // Note position of []
  }
```